# SVG: Understanding the Translate command

Tags: svg, transform

From what I understand, the SVG Translate transformation offsets the coordinates by a given X and a given Y. So if drawing something at (80,100) and applying a translate(-10,-10) would draw the object at (70,90).

That being said, I have an SVG file that has a page width of 744 by 1052. One of the groups  tag applies a transformation of translate(-5774.2676,3117.0866). What I'm trying to understand is how this is not completely off the entire page (which it isn't). Can someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Likely better asked at StackOverflow. This is more of a code syntax question than graphic design.

Comment: @DA01 Just posted the question over there too. Thanks

Comment: Closing this question since it was cross-posted at SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be best to take a look at SVG specification, into [Coordinate Systems, Transformations and Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) section. In SVG it's possible to “define” or rather “redefine” coordinate system – there's a default one but it's not an “absolute” coordinate system. That could explain why object you mentioned is still visible. Without complete SVG file one can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least two possible reasons: either

1. the untranslated coordinates of the group *are* far off the page, and the `translate` moves them *into* the page area, or
2. the same group, or one of its parents, has a `scale` (or `matrix`) transformation applied that shrinks it down, so that the actual translation in page coordinates is much less.

Of course, it could also be both.